# Google stats not working on stream

Tags: jwplayer, google-analytics-api

Where is the mistake?

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.tv/jwplayer/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("http://www.site.tv/jwplayer/player.swf","mpl","425","317","9");
so.addParam("allowfullscreen","true");
so.addParam("allowscriptaccess","always");
so.addParam("wmode","opaque");
so.addVariable("controlbar","over");
so.addVariable('image','http://www.site.tv/images/bg_online_player.png');
so.addVariable('file','myStream');
so.addVariable('streamer','rtmp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1935/live/');
so.addVariable("plugins","gapro-1,adtvideo");
so.addVariable("adtvideo.config", "http://www.site.tv/ad/stream.xml");
so.addVariable("gapro.accountid","UA-xxxxxxxxx-x");
so.addVariable("gapro.idstring","streamer");
so.addVariable("gapro.trackstarts","true");
so.write("player");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a mistake in your code. You should be passing idstring with pipe symbol

Instead of `so.addVariable("gapro.idstring","streamer");`
the code should be as follows

```
so.addVariable("gapro.idstring","||streamer||");
```